# How to add web app to user home screen?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, web-applications, webapp2

As the title says, I would like to show a small popup containing a button at the end of my web site to hint users to add my website to their phone's home screen. I found a tutorial here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/add-to-home-screen/#0, which solved my issue on Android but this way just works just only on Android and https method. I would prefer that this popup must work on Android, iOS, http and https. Would anyone here know how to solve this? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For Android, the Add To Home Screen prompt *requires* HTTPS (or localhost), so it's not possible to do it on HTTP.

For Safari on iOS, you can configure the home screen icon & launch appearance [with meta tags](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html), but a prompt system is not currently available, so users will need to add the app manually.